# Symfony2 Result is null by OneToOne Reference

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm beginner with Symfony2.

My goal is to translate all old intranet tools from buggy, freestyle-code written in PHP 4 to Object Oriented and modern code. At the moment I have a problem with Doctrine while using `OneToOne` mapping.

I have a table company, which contains a column called `extent_id` that is a reference to the table `company_extent`.

I await now have: in my `Company` object the right `company_extent` referenced.

This is what I have tried:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="CompanyExtent", inversedBy="company")
     * @JoinColumn(name="extent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $extent;
}

class CompanyExtent
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company", mappedBy="extent")
     */
    private $company;
}
```

But, if I dump my company object I get:

```
object(Dsa\ServiceMeetingBundle\Entity\Company)[274]
    protected 'extentId' => int 1
    private 'extent' => null
    protected 'stretchId' => int 1
```

Comment: I suspect you are working with id's and not objects.  There is no need for you to have an extendId property in your company entity.  Go through the example in the documentation in detail to learn the basics of Doctrine's Object Relation Manager http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: Can you show use the code you use to generate the dump? (and add the full entities please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an "ID" attribute for each entity that you created.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 */
class Company
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="CompanyExtent", inversedBy="company")
     * @JoinColumn(name="extent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $extent; 
}
```

In your annotation `@JoinColumn(name="extent_id", referencedColumnName="id")` you are using a reference that does not exists.

```
class CompanyExtent
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company", mappedBy="extent")
     */
    private $company;
}
```

And as mentioned by @cerad, I advice you read about Doctrine's Object Relation Manager. It's a very important part of development.

Comment: Hey, in my real Entity  I have Ids.

I'm reading all, what I can find. But in the moment, I can't find any example for get working this.

Comment: @Chrisotopher you can take a look on doctrine official docs: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html